# Fancybox 4 in fullscreen mode

Tags: fancybox

I am upgrading to FancyBox 4.0.5 (from v3). I cannot understand how to run fullscreen mode by default when I'm clicking on carousel image. I could run fullscreen in v3 with no problem. I have tried static config options and events and nothing worked for me. There were no errors in console (very strange...). I am using it like this:

```
import {Fancybox} from "@fancyapps/ui";
import {Carousel} from "@fancyapps/ui";
import {Panzoom} from "@fancyapps/ui";
import {Fullscreen} from "@fancyapps/ui/src/shared/utils/Fullscreen";

$(document).ready(function () {
    const itemImagesDetail = new Carousel(document.querySelector(".carousel"), {
        'slidesPerPage': 1,
    });

// Customize Fancybox
Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox="gallery"]', {
    Carousel: {
        on: {
            change: (that) => {
                itemImagesDetail.slideTo(itemImagesDetail.findPageForSlide(that.page), 
                {
                    friction: 0,
                });
              
            },
        },
    },
    Thumbs: {
        autoStart: false,
    },
    Toolbar: {
        display: [
            { id: "prev", position: "center" },
            { id: "counter", position: "center" },
            { id: "next", position: "center" },
            "zoom",
            "slideshow",
            "fullscreen",
            "download",
            "close",
        ],
    },
    Fancybox: {
        // ...
    },
});
```

Any ideas please? THANKS FOR YOUR HELP.

Comment: Sorry, I'll update docs to cover this.

Answer (score 1):

It would be like this:

```js
Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox="gallery"]', {
  Image: {
    zoom: false,
  },

  fullscreen: {
    autoStart: true,
  },
});
```